# What kind of ARMA-GARCH model is that?

Tags: garch, models, arima, order

My question is what kind of ARMA-GARCH model is the following equation and how to specify it in [*rugarch*](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rugarch) `R` module:

$$r_{t+1}- r_t = \alpha_0 + \alpha_1r_t+\alpha_2V_t+\epsilon_{t+1},$$
$$\epsilon_{t+1} \sim N(0,V_t), \text{and}$$
$$V_t = \beta_0 + \beta_1r_t + \beta_2V_{t-1}+\beta_3 \epsilon_t^2.$$